# XMPP Openfire Messages inserting late in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmpp, openfire

> **Goal:-** Inserting messages in faster way to database.

I have integrated xmpp openfire one-to-one chat over my website.

I am using **Monitoring Service**  plugin for storing messages into the database.

What i am facing is when user send a message from one user to another user at that time messages are stored in the database.

Now messages are stored, but i am facing issue of inserting messages late into the database.

I am loading messages via ajax call when user clicks on another user message thread but if the messages does not store in the database ofcourse it will not be returned in ajax call history.

I have done following configuration settings for **Monitoring Service** plugin.

[image: Messages stored late into the database.]

I've find alternative solution of modifying **Monitoring Service** plugin's jar file and decrements inserting seconds but ultimately it will affect database.

Eg. Every minute 50 users send 10 messages at that time database may hanged.

Any help would be appreciated if i can store the messages into the database as faster way!

Comment: There is caching system of openfire, need to change message caching value to be quick, but reduce effectiveness

Comment: How can i change that cache values ?

Comment: @Kassav' How can i change the cache values ? or there is any sufficient way to do this ?

Comment: in System Properties, check for cache properties, will will find one related to messages caching

Comment: Anyone facing same issue ?